# <TextInput /> not working with numeric values(age)

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am building a simple form in react native that just takes name, age and email from the user and posts in into an api. I am having problem in the  component.

```
import { View, Text, Button, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const ApiDataComponent = () => {
     const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [age, setAge] = useState(0)
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')

return (
<View>
<TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder='Enter your name'
        value={name}
        onChangeText={(text) => setName(text)}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder='Enter your age'
        keyboardType='numeric'
        value={age}
        onChangeText={(text) => setAge(text)}
      />

      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder='Enter your email'
        value={email}
        onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
      />
</View>
)
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
input: {
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'black',
    margin: 15
  }
})
```

To correct this I have changes the type of age to string but that will just cause problems for me in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is because you are setting the age state with a string value, which is not compatible with the numeric keyboard input. To address this, you can keep the age state as a number and make sure you convert it to a string only when displaying it in the TextInput. Here's how you can do it:

```
import { View, Text, Button, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const ApiDataComponent = () => {
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [age, setAge] = useState(0);
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');

return (
    <View>
    <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder='Enter your name'
        value={name}
        onChangeText={(text) => setName(text)}
    />
    <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder='Enter your age'
        keyboardType='numeric'
        value={age.toString()} {/* Convert number to string for display */}
        onChangeText={(text) => setAge(parseInt(text, 10))} {/* Parse string input to integer */}
    />

    <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder='Enter your email'
        value={email}
        onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
    />
    </View>
);
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
input: {
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'black',
    margin: 15,
    padding: 5, // Adding some padding for better visual appearance
},
});

export default ApiDataComponent;
```